# Restrict special user and host of the ftp in the Linux Instance

Tags: linux, ssh, ftp, amazon-ec2, aws

I am using WinScp for connecting FTP to a Linux Instance and I want to restrict special user and host.

I installed `plesk` on my Linux EC2 instance and I thought it uses `proftpd` for ftp service and `xinetd` for service name.

I configured `/etc/proftpd.conf` and `sudo service xinetd restart` But it did not work.

I decided to change the `/etc/hosts.allow` and `/etc/hosts.deny` and config like this

**/etc/hosts.allow**:

```
sshd: 1.2.3.4
```

**/etc/hosts.deny**:

```
sshd: ALL
```

It's working. But I want to restrict special user and host means one IP address can access with only one username.

Next, I tried:

```
sshd: username@ipaddress
```

But it did not work.

My final goal is to allow one user to access with one IP address to one folder.

Comment: I am using /etc/ssh/sshd_config file for the restrict folder, it is working properly but not working in the specific folder